# How to host a web server in ionic 3 app which can respond to GET/POST requests

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, webserver

I am building an app where I need to host a web server in my ionic app which can respond to `GET/POST/PUT/DELETE` requests.

Use Case:
I need to send some data from my PC to my mobile app(where the server should be hosted) and then I will print that data from my mobile app.

I am already trying this [package](https://github.com/bykof/cordova-plugin-webserver.git) , but this isn't working as expected.
The code for this is:

`home.ts`

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { WebServer } from '@ionic-native/web-server';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {

  private port: number;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    private webServer: WebServer) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.port = 1234;

    this.webServer.onRequest().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      const res: any = {
        status: 200,
        body: '',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'text/html'
        }
      };

      this.webServer.sendResponse(data.requestId, res)
        .catch((error: any) => console.error(error));
    });

    this.webServer.start(this.port)
      .catch((error: any) => console.error(error));

    console.log('server started at port : ', this.port);

  }

  ionViewWillEnter() {

  }

  ionViewWillUnload() {
    // this.webServer.stop();
  }




}
```

So, when I try to run this app on my android device, the app runs successfully, but I don't get any response on calling the web server with GET or POST request(with Postman; my android device and my PC are in same wifi network, and I am using the IP of my android device with defined port to call the server ). 
So, I don't know if its working or not.
If anyone has done something like this, then please help me.

Comment: I'm planning on a similar feature for an upcoming project - were you able to find a solution?

Comment: Yes @MattBeckett, I made the package to work for me which I mentioned in the question. I will soon post an answer to this.